# How to know SqlException error number?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have a problem with SqlException. In my c# code, when I try to insert data in database, I get next error: cannot insert duplicate key in object error number
I made a constraint in Sql Server. But I need to know error code of this exception? What I should make?

```
       try{
      connect c = new connection();
      DataTable d = c.query("INSERT INTO User (code, name, surname) VALUES ('"+code+"',           '"+name+"', '"+surname+"')");
      }
      catch(SqlException e)
      {
     if(e.Number == ???)
      {
       MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you can't add duplicate data");
       }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to `switch` on the *error number*:

```
switch (exc.Errors[0].Number){
    case 17:
    case 4060:
    case 18456:
    case 547:
        break;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try this for starters to see what error number you're getting:

```
try
{
    connect c = new connection();
    DataTable d = c.query("INSERT INTO User (code, name, surname) VALUES ('"+code+"',           '"+name+"', '"+surname+"')");
}
catch(SqlException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Number.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It's constraint, which was made in Sql Server. Ok, I edit with code

Comment: I Try like this, but can't get a messagebox.

  if (exc.Number == 2601)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("sorry");
                    }

Comment: Yes it should have been a comment, but I don't get an "add comment" link for the question :(